# How to trace errors via Eclipse? How to connect the phone to the DDMS? Some drivers missing

Tags: android, eclipse, ddms

I want to trace an app's error that occurs at a certain time.
A coleague told me I had to start eclipse, open the DDMS, plug in the phone in MTP mode and when I use the app, the log is going to show the errors.

I tried that but phone is not showing in the DDMS.
When I plugged it in windows 7, it couldnt find 2 drivers - SAMSUNG_ANDROID and CDC.

What do I do?

Phone is Galaxy s2 android ersion is 2.3.4

I have USB debugging enabled on my phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following :

1). Download & install samsung Kies driver on your PC.(http://www.mkyong.com/android/where-to-download-samsung-galaxy-s2-usb-driver/)

2). Turn on USB debugging on your device: Settings -> Applications ->Development -> USB debugging

3). Connect your samsung galaxy with the PC.

5). Run the app mannually (Select the device at runtime).

Log cat is used trace the errors:

If logcat is not visible go to Window -> show view -> other -> android -> log cat

Answer (score 1):

Install the drivers for samsung. Connect your device to PC and Make USB Debugging on.

Application/Development/USB Debugging.

Go to Run Configuration : And select your device to debug you application.

You can easily debug using logcat .

Answer (score 1):

Did you enable the usb debugging on your phone? http://www.droidviews.com/how-to-enable-developer-optionsusb-debugging-mode-on-devices-with-android-4-2-jelly-bean/?ModPagespeed=noscript

Answer (score 1):

First Update your google usb Driver in SDK manager. then Connect Your Phone in  USB Debugging  mode . In windows go to Device manager where  you can find your mobile in other device tab.  right click on the device and select update driver.
from that popup window select driver from SDK android-sdks\extras\google\usb_driver\androidwinusb86  and update it .then you can find mobile on DDMS.